# Файл подкачки в Windows 10

Tags: windows

Во всех играх используется только файл подкачки а не оперативная память причём всегда около 10 ГБ (смотрел через MSI Afterburner) и сколько бы я не ставил или вовсе отключал его всё равно он работает.

Answer (score 0):

Оперативка не может не использоваться. Возможно, либо плохо читает показания ОЭД, либо не настроен.

Comment: В диспетчере задач тоже самое

Comment: Что за игра? Не фризит? Какой ФПС?

Comment: Я же сказал во всех играх. Не фризит не лагает, но у меня установлен SSD который от такого сдохнет учитывая то что он очень дешёвый

Comment: Всё равно, производительность SSD даже с DDR1 особо не валяется. Я уверен, что у вас только с отображением проблемы. Возможные виновники: Чипсет, Винда